# How to make sure anaconda environment is properly configured to import packages

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I'm trying to get an anaconda environment to work in Jupyter notebook with all of the packages I've included in the environment, but the packages are unable to import in jupyter notebook. The environment I created uses Python 3.7 and has all of the anaconda packages and librosa included.

I've tried using the Python 2 kernel and pandas is able to get imported. If I try to the Python 3 kernel, the kernel constantly shows up as dead, despite just installing the anaconda distribution. I was able to import sys in the environment I created but nothing else. The kernel also sometimes says it's in idle when the jupyter notebook cell indicates that it is running. Is this an issue with how jupyter interacts with Python 3.7 installation of anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

When working in a file(notebook), click on the kernel menu and select change kernel and pick your environment.

For example if your environment was named my_env and your project was named file, select Python [conda env:file-my_env].

Let me know if this helps!